# How to change the current language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
languages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString* preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:14];
NSString *chn = @"zh-Hans";
NSString *eng = @"en";
[languages replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:chn];
[languages replaceObjectAtIndex:14 withObject:eng];
defs = (NSUserDefaults*)languages;
```

And I can change the content of NSUserDefaults defs. But it doesn't have an effect on applelanguage. I need to store the first object of defs as the current language.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but you should remove `languages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`, as you overwrite it the line just below, it's a memory leak.

Comment: Wat you want to do? May be is other solution for your problem.

Comment: Actually in defs I change the english language to chinese simplified and then i want to add chinese language as current language so that it change my keyboard language. pls help me

Comment: can you PLs tell me how can i use multiple languages in my apps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to set the current language for the user.

That's not supported in the iOS sdk; the user must do this herself in settings.

If you explain your motivation for trying to do this, perhaps I could offer a solution.

Comment: thanxs, Actually in defs I change the english language to chinese simplified and then i want to add chinese language as current language so that it change my keyboard language. pls help me

Comment: can you PLs tell me how can i use multiple languages in my apps

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

languages = [[languages mutableCopy] autorelease];

[languages replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"zh-Hans"];
[languages replaceObjectAtIndex:14 withObject:@"en"]
[defaults setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

But are you sure you want to impose a language on the user? He always has the choice of changing the language through the settings application.

You will also need to make sure you have set the localized string correctly. You should go through [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html) document if you haven't already.

Comment: No reason to make a copy of the mutableList before putting it into the defaults.

Comment: can you PLs tell me how can i use multiple languages in my apps

Comment: @Eiko you were right about it. Both `copy`s were unnecessary.

Comment: @Deepak: Actually the first mutableCopy is necessary as you should get an immutable array from the defaults, no matter what you had put in there.

Comment: @sandy_iphone I am not sure if you can change the keyboard language programmatically.

Comment: @Deepak From the docs: "The returned object is immutable, even if the value you originally set was mutable".

Comment: @Eiko Well if the doc says so, I can't contest that. But its strange that I am getting a mutable list as I posted the code after testing. You are right, I shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSMutableArray *languages= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString *chn=@"zh-Hans";
    NSString *eng=@"en";
    [languages replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:chn];
    [languages replaceObjectAtIndex:14 withObject:eng];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSMutableArray *languagesAterChange= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSLog(@"Lang:%@  | %@",[languagesAterChange objectAtIndex:0],[languagesAterChange objectAtIndex:14]);
```

There you go.